# Find global database name in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

I wants to find global database name of database say 'myDb'. The database is created by someone else and hence I wants to know it.

I am using Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the below query to find the `GLOBAL NAME`,

```
SELECT * FROM GLOBAL_NAME;
```